# Floats in CSS not sitting properly

Tags: css

I am trying to set up a grid with css. its a box layout with different sections but I can't get the far right section positioned correctly.

The div's should flow as follows:

Box 1 left
  Box 2 beside box 1
  Box 3 beside box 2
  Box 4 sits underneath boxes 2 and 3
  Box 5 same dimensions as box 1 but it floats to the right of boxes 2 and 3 and 4

I would post an image but it says I don't have a high enough score to.

**CSS:**

```
#container { width:960px; margin:auto; position:relative; height:350px;  }
.box1 { width:240px; height:350px; float:left; }
.box2 { width:240px; float:left; height:175px; }
.box3 { width:240px; float:left; height:175px; }
.box4 { width:480px; float:left; height:175px; }
.box5 { width:240px; height:350px; float:right; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box1"><span>Major Events</span></div>
<div class="box2"><span>Tours & Maps</span></div>
<div class="box3"><span>Visiting Information</span></div>
<div class="box4"><span>Video</span></div> 
<div class="box5">Discovery Centers</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyway, the width of the boxes is bigger than the container width. You should use a CSS framework like Bootstrap or Foundation.

Comment: Your CSS will lead to box1, box2 and box3 on one line, and then box3 will start on a second line since it will not bit on the same line with boxes 1,2,3.  At this point, where do you want box5 to be?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:inline-block` instead of using `float`.

```
#container { width:960px; margin:auto; position:relative; height:350px; }
.box1 { width:240px; height:350px; display:inline-block; }
.box2 { width:240px; height:175px; display:inline-block;}
.box3 { width:240px; height:175px; display:inline-block; }
.box4 { width:480px; height:175px; display:inline-block;}
.box5 { width:240px; height:350px; display:inline-block; }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9X8YF/)**

Answer (score 0):

Craighead got half of the good answer with `display: inline-block;`.

If you do this, you will have a small margin. To remove it, just set the `font-size` of `#container` to 0.

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLMuH/2/)

```
#container { width:960px; margin:auto; position:relative; height:350px; font-size:0; background: blue;}
.box1 { width:240px; height:350px; display:inline-block; background : red;}
.box2 { width:240px;  height:175px;  display:inline-block;background : orange}
.box3 { width:240px; height:175px; display:inline-block;background : pink; }
.box4 { width:480px; height:175px;  display:inline-block;background : green;}
.box5 { width:240px; height:350px; display:inline-block; background : red;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to achieve this is as follows.

In your HTML, add a `div.sub-wrap` around `.box2`, `.box3`, `.box4`:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box1"><span>Major Events</span></div>
    <div class="sub-wrap">
        <div class="box2"><span>Tours & Maps</span></div>
        <div class="box3"><span>Visiting Information</span></div>
        <div class="box4"><span>Video</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box5">Discovery Centers</div>
</div>
```

For your CSS, float `.sub-wrap` to the left and add `overflow: auto` to create a new
block-formatting context to keep the child floats in one panel.

```
#container div {
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}
div.sub-wrap {
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 480px;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/SJa5Y/

The results look like:

[image: floated layout visual]

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/U3vkr/

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-left"><span class="box">Major Events</span></div>
    <div class="grid-center">
        <div class="box box50"><span>Tours & Maps</span></div>
        <div class="box box50"><span>Visiting Information</span></div>
        <div class="box footer"><span>Video</span></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="grid-right"><span class="box">Discovery Centers</span></div>
</div><!-- /.grid -->
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    height:350px; 
}
.grid-left,
.grid-center,
.grid-right {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:solid 1px #d0d0d0;
}
.grid-center {
    width:50%;
}
.box {
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box50 {
    width:50%;
    float: left;
}
.grid-center .box {
    height:175px;
}
.footer {
    clear:both;
    border-top:#ddd solid 1px;
}
```